# Removing 2nd item from a queue, using another queue as an ADT

Tags: python, abstract-data-type

```
class Queue:

    def __init__(self):
        self._contents = []

    def enqueue(self, obj):
        self._contents.append(obj)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self._contents.pop(0)

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._contents == []

class remove_2nd(Queue):

    def dequeue(self):

        first_item = Queue.dequeue(self)
        # Condition if the queue length isn't greater than two
        if self.is_empty():
            return first_item
        else:
            # Second item to return
            second_item = Queue.dequeue(self)
            # Add back the first item to the queue (stuck here)
```

The remove_2nd class is basically a queue except if the length of the queue is greater than two, then you remove the 2nd item every dequeue. If it isn't then you do the same as a normal queue. I am only allowed to use the methods in the queue to finish remove_2nd.

My algorithm:

If queue is bigger than two:

Lets say my queue is 1 2 3 4

I would first remove the first item so it becomes

2 3 4

I would then remove the 2nd item and that will be the returned value, so then it will be

3 4

I would then add back the first item as wanted

1 3 4

The problem is, I don't know how to add it back. Enqueue puts it at the end, so basically it would be 3 4 1. I was thinking of reversing the 3 4, but I don't know how to do that either. Any help?

Just want to point out, I'm not allowed to call on _contents or allowed to create my own private variable for the remove_2nd class. This should strictly be done using the queue adt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the queue back in the right order after removing the first two elements, you'll need to remove all the other elements as well. Once the queue is empty, you can add back the first element and all the other elements one by one.

How exactly you keep track of the values you're removing until you can add them again is a somewhat tricky question that depends on the rules of your assignment. If you can use Python's normal types (as local variables, not as new attributes for your class), you can put them in a list or a `deque` from the `collections` module. But you can also just use another `Queue` instance (an instance of the base type, not your subclass).

Try something like this in your `else` clause:

```
second_item = Queue.dequeue(self)   # note, this could be written super().dequeue()

temp = Queue()
while not self.is_empty():
    temp.enqueue(Queue.dequeue(self))

self.enqueue(first_item)
while not temp.is_empty()
    self.enqueue(temp.dequeue())

return second_item
```

As I commented in the code, `Queue.dequeue(self)` can be written more "pythonically" using the `super` builtin. The exact details of the call depend on which version of Python you're using (Python 3's `super` is much fancier than Python 2's version).

In Python 2, you have to explicitly pass `self` and your current class, so the call would be `super(self, dequeue_2nd).dequeue()`. In Python 3, you simply use `super().dequeue()` and it "magically" takes care of everything (in reality, the compiler figures out the class at compile time, and adds some extra code to let it find `self` at run time).

For your simple code with only basic inheritance, there's no difference between using `super` or explicitly looking up the base class by name. But in more complicated situations, using `super` is very important. If you ever use multiple inheritance, calling overridden methods with `super` is often the only way to get things to work sanely.

Comment: Thanks a lot and also for the super() tip.

Answer (score 1):

```
def insert(self,position,element):
    self._contents.insert(position,element)
```

Comment: you add an element in any position in your list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they questioner is not allowed to do any operations on `self._contents` at all. They're only allowed to use the methods defined by `Queue`, not access its "private" data.